# Login protect root, but allow all in subdir? (Apache)

Tags: apache-2.4, authentication

I currently have a setup where the root is login (password) protected, but I need to open up a specific subdir to the public. I can't seem to accomplish this no matter which combinations of commands I try. Currently, my settings (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`) are:

```
# access settings
<Location />
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Password Protected Area"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
</Location>

<Location /var/www/html/some_dir>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Satisfy Any
        Allow from all
</Location>
```

Note: I restarted apache after every change.

Versions:

- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
- Apache 2.4.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Apache version is 2.4.7, but your configuration seems like it was from Apache 2.2. See [Runtime Configuration Changes](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time):

> Access control
>
> In 2.2, access control based on client hostname, IP
>   address, and other characteristics of client requests was done using
>   the directives `Order`, `Allow`, `Deny`, and `Satisfy`.
>
> In 2.4, such access
>   control is done in the same way as other authorization checks, using
>   the new module [mod_authz_host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html). The old access control idioms should be
>   replaced by the new authentication mechanisms.

Also, the [`Location` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location) limits the scope of the enclosed directives by URL, while the [`Directory` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) is used for file-systen locations, like your `/var/www/html/some_dir`.

The [mod_authn_core `AuthType`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_core.html#authtype) documentation has a textbook example of the very same situation, with explanation:

> The authentication type `None` disables authentication. When
>   authentication is enabled, it is normally inherited by each subsequent
>   configuration section, unless a different authentication type is
>   specified. If no authentication is desired for a subsection of an
>   authenticated section, the authentication type `None` may be used; in
>   the following example, clients may access the `/www/docs/public`
>   directory without authenticating:
>
> ```
> <Directory "/www/docs">
>     AuthType Basic
>     AuthName Documents
>     AuthBasicProvider file
>     AuthUserFile "/usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords"
>     Require valid-user
> </Directory>
>
> <Directory "/www/docs/public">
>     AuthType None
>     Require all granted
> </Directory>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There are some other related questions, such as [here](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/access-protected-dir), but their solutions did not work for me. By trial and error (including the order of the settings), I found some settings that did the trick for me:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/some_dir>
        AuthType None
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

Notice the change from `Location` to `Directory`. Don't know if that's significant.

Comment: Read the documentation instead of trial and error. You still have an unnecessary and [deprecated](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html) `Satisfy` directive and [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) isn't related to authentication at all.

Comment: The documentation for Apache is not good. It's faster to just try stuff and google things. Hence making this Q&A so others can use the google stuff method in the future. :)

Comment: Documentation for Apache is excellent. Strange attitude. Q&A sites are a good help when still confused after reading the documentation. Compensating own laziness by some free help from professionals is a bit disrespectful.

Comment: Not lazy. Often read docs, but usually not very helpful due to a near total lack of examples (e.g. Python docs).